# How does this SQL query pair colleges with their the max GPA of their students?

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm learning about SQL through Stanford's Databases course on EdX, taught by Jennifer Widom.

In it, she uses an example of a database with 3 tables:
College - US colleges, their state etc
Student - Students in the US, their GPA etc
Apply - Applications of students to colleges, their major etc

She says the following query should pair the colleges with the highest GPA of their applicants.
So it would might return a row for Stanford, paired with GPA of their top performing applicant,
and another row for Berkeley, paired with the GPA of their top performing applicant.

```
select distinct College.cName, state, GPA
from College, Apply, Student
where College.cName = Apply.cName
  and Apply.sID = Student.sID
  and GPA >= all
          (select GPA from Student, Apply
           where Student.sID = Apply.sID
             and Apply.cName = College.cName);
```

What I don't understand is how this query is able to find the top performing applicant within EACH college - to me it looks as though the >= all(...) part just compares to ALL students who have applied for any college. Can anyone explain how this works?

Comment: `JOIN`.  `JOIN`.  `JOIN`.  It is long past time to learn proper, explicit, **standard**, readable `JOIN` syntax.

Comment: You may get a better answer if you include the SQL statements needed to create the tables and/or use http://sqlfiddle.com/ to create a shareable link to a database with those tables.

Comment: @Gordon Linoff This code is copied from a course I was recommended, though admittedly it is a little old.
I've come across the `JOIN` clause as well, though wasn't aware it offered any advantage over the above method. Is it solely for readability?

Comment: @Zev Spitz Unfortunately the course doesn't provide the creation statements or the database for the example, they just run through it in a video, then get give us a different database with some questions. Thanks for the sqlfiddle tip though

Comment: @ChunkyLover53 . . . That is very sad.  A course that is not teaching proper `JOIN` syntax is not really teaching the current version of the language.

Comment: @Gordon Linoff I've now watched a bit more of the course and they've now moved on to the JOIN clauses

Comment: @ChunkyLover53 . . . The course should simply never introduce commas.  It is archaic syntax, less powerful, and most people just find it less useful (it doesn't require join conditions, for instance).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> the `>= all(...)` part just compares to ALL students who have applied for any college.

Not quite. It makes sense to compare against all students, but only those who applied to the specific college in the current row of the outer query. In other words, if the college in the current row is `Berkeley`, the query needs to look at all the students who applied to `Berkeley` to get the highest GPA for Berkeley applicants.

The subquery in the parentheses is limited to applications from the college in the current row of the outer query, because it's filtering on an expression from the outer query: `College.cName`:

```sql
             and Apply.cName = College.cName);
```

If you try to run the subquery on its own:

```sql
select GPA 
from Student, Apply
where Student.sID = Apply.sID
    and Apply.cName = College.cName
```

you'll get an error, because `College.cName` doesn't exist in the subquery.

Comment: Perfect thanks, I hadn't realised the College.cName i nthe inner query was coming from the outer query